Auto redirect to specific page if non author post
I need help with Wordpress, here's the idea:

I have a Custom Post Type called: History.
Posts are published publicly and are attributed to its own Author.

My goal:

From the front end, if another Author would try to access a link of one of the posts of which he's not the author then it redirects him to a specific page.
Except for Admin accounts.

This code is Working Well, but what if i want to Exclude Admin or Editor Role ? :)
   add_action( 'get_header', 'wpso_author_redirection' );

function wpso_author_redirection() {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $current_post_details = get_post( get_the_ID(), ARRAY_A );
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        if ( $user_id !== absint( $current_post_details['post_author'] ) ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
        }
    }
}

Regards,

You will need to get user object instead of ID to get more info about the user.
add_action( 'get_header', 'wpso_author_redirection' );
function wpso_author_redirection() {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_id = $user->ID;

        // Skip redirection for 'Administrator' or 'Editor'
        if ( array_intersect( ['administrator', 'editor'], $user->roles ) ) {
            return; // Allow access
        }

        // Redirect if the user is not the post author
        $post_author = (int) get_post_field( 'post_author', get_the_ID() );
        if ( $user_id !== $post_author ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
            exit;
        }
    }
}

